# How can they manufacture a high fara capacitor (1F, 100F)?

Tags: capacitor

In the theory, the capacitance of a capacitor can be calculated by formulas
C = epsilon x A / d. And if we use this formula to calculate the area of a 1F capacitor(with d = 1m), the result of A is a very large number and not really. But in reality, I see they can make super fara capacitor such as 1F or even 100F. How can they do that ? What's special of these kind of capacitor ? [image]

[image]

Comment: Your formula assumes a single flat linear plane. Supercaps aren't.

Comment: d << 1m and epsilon > 1

Comment: What's a "fara"?

Comment: @OlinLathrop It's a measurement of capatance.

Comment: @Majenko, it's a joke, "Farad" is the unit ;-)

Comment: @JarrodChristman re-read my last comment, and pay close attention while you do :P

Comment: @Majenko, Ah lol

Comment: @JarrodChristman Maybe I should have said "crapacitance"? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try reading [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor) sometime.  The answer to your question is right there in black-and-white:

> Supercapacitors are constructed with two metal foils (current collectors), each coated with an electrode material such as activated carbon. The collectors serve as the power connection between the electrode material and the external terminals of the capacitor. **Specifically to the electrode material is its very large surface area. In this example the activated carbon is electrochemically etched, so that the surface of the material is about a factor 100,000 larger than the smooth surface.**

So the surface area for a given pair electrode dimensions is considerably larger than the size of the actual plate size.  It's basically 3D.  For example, take a 1m² sheet of tinfoil, then scrunch it up into a ball.  Open it out again into a rough square of half the size it was.  You still have a 1m² surface area, but it doesn't take up 1m² or your desk.